# Adding facebook sdk to android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to add the Facebook SDK to work in the emulator. I am following this tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

I don't know what does this line mean:

```
adb install %HOMEPATH%\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\bin\FBAndroid-3.5.apk
```

the android sdk is in : `C:\android-windows-sdk`

and the facebook sdk is in: `E:\facebook-android-sdk-3.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass adb the path to your apk file. `%HOMEPATH%` resolves to `\Documents and Settings\<your username>` on Windows XP and below, and `\Users\<your username>` on Windows Vista and above

Since your Facebook SDK is in `E:\facebook-android-sdk-3.5`, try using:

```
adb install E:\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\bin\FBAndroid-3.5.apk
```